# Lerna: not killing processes after CTRL+C

Tags: node.js, reactjs, monorepo, lerna

I'm starting out with lerna and I set up two packages, both have a "start" script.

client-platform: runs on port 3000 (runs react app)
server-api: runs on port 3030 (runs node.js express server)

I run the app and the server with `lerna run start --stream` and when I hit CTRL+C,
it leaves the processes running and I need to kill them manually with

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
taskkil /PID <PID> /f
```

Is there any way to make it work on CTRL+C?
or any other more convenient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the github issue, it is a known issue. Workaround for now is to downgrade lerna version in your devDependencies to `3.22.1`

https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2284#issuecomment-938068812